# Docker image unable to add my JSON credential key to my Google Cloud Natural Language service client

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform

I created a Spring Boot Java application in Eclipse that connects to Google Cloud Natural Language service to analyze text for me.
I created a Docker image of it and it fails to run yet it works in Eclipse for me.

I read in my JSON key like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = GoogleNlpApplication.class.getClassLoader().getSystemResourceAsStream("AvayaNlp-e422dbca92e5.json");

credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(inputStream));
```

My pom file for the spotify Docker plugin:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>docker-build</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>build</name>
                    <value>docker</value>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <imageName>googlenlp2vi</imageName>
                            <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                            <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                            <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory 
                                of the image -->
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>

                        <executions>

                            <execution>
                                <id>default</id>
                                <!-- phase>install</phase -->
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                    <!-- goal>push</goal -->
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <finalName>googlenlp2vi</finalName>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

The directory of the application:
[image: Directory]

Then in Docker toolbox I run:
1.mvn clean install
2.mvn clean package -Dbuild=docker

The error I get:
[image]

It runs fine on Eclipse, is the docker image not using the imports of the java file?

### Update Solution:

I ended creating a new directory in resources:

```
src
 |
  main
   |
    resources
     |
      test
       |
        AvayaNlp-e422dbca92e5.json
```

Then used:

```
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:test/*.json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        for (Resource r : resources) {
            inputStream = r.getInputStream();
        }

credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(inputStream));
```

And now the docker image is able to access the json key in the jar now, though it will grab all JSON's if you have more than one in the folder within resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make `AvayaNlp-e422dbca92e5.json` available at the location where your JAR expects to find it when you run this image.

I'm not sufficiently familiar with the `docker-maven-plugin` to provide you precise guidance but, assuming `AvayaNlp-e422dbca92e5.json` is in `${PWD}/secrets` and you wish to mount this to `/secrets/` in your container image, the `docker run` command would take the form:

```
docker run ... --volume=${PWD}/secrets:/secrets ... [[your-image]]
```

How are you running the container to generate the error?

Does Maven run your container image after it's created?

HTH!

Comment: I see that Spotify has effectively deprecated this plugin: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#status-bug-fix-only

Comment: In Docker Toolbox, I type 'mvn clean install' and then after its finished I type 'mvn clean package -Dbuild=docker' which builds the image. Then I run it by 'docker run googlenlp2v' which runs the java application until it generates the error. The location of my JSON is in the resource folder in the application.

Comment: I suspect (guess!) that the JSON key isn't being copied with your app and thus your code is not able to find it. Are you able to paste (or reference) the stacktrace directly rather than use a screenshot? I don't know whether the `FROM: java` includes this, but you may try shelling into the container and checking the directory: `docker run --interactive --tty --entrypoint=/bin/bash [[your-image]]`. If not `/bin/bash` try `/bin/sh`. Neither may work, unfortunately. If you get a shell then try listing `src/main/resources`. It may not be at root.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should not use `<image>java</image>` see https://hub.docker.com/_/java. You should (!) be able to replace it with `<image>openjdk:7</image>` see https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/

Comment: I wasn't able to shell that command but I tried uisng a print statement to see if I could print out the json. Turns out it can't so the JSON is missing somehow I think. I changed my <baseImage> tag to openjdk:8 and I also added a <include> AvayaNlp-e422dbca92e5.json at <resource> tag in the pom.xml. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you able to browse the jar file to confirm the JSON file is in it? Are you able to execute the jar standalone (`java -jar /target/[name].jar`)? IIUC the resources directory should be included by Maven by default.

Comment: I extracted the jar using winrar and I found the file in the folder [jarname]\BOOT-INF\classes.  My application.properties spring boot file and the JSON key is in there. So all of the files from my resource folder is in there.

Comment: I created a simple repro of your case. I'm not using Spring Boot but am using the old Spotify plugin. My solution works. The `key.json` is in the jar's root and the code finds it.

Comment: I have updated the post with a solution that can grab all JSON in the resources. Unfortunately, if there is more then one key in the folder  and you want to create multiple service clients, a new folder should be created for each JSON file and then grab then respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In Dockerfile, add the json file at appropriate location.
Use `ADD` dockerfile command.

Comment: I don't have a docker file. So you want me to create one and use   <dockerDirectory>docker</dockerDirectory> to use the docker file? I currently have my JSON in my resource folder then how do I add it?

Comment: Otherwise you can push this file as part of deployment spec. Create configmap and mount the file on desired location.